# "THREE.NearestFilter" or "THREE.LinearFilter" Causes the Black Plane

Tags: javascript, three.js

While I was working with THREE.js library, I got that kind of notification:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter
>   should be set to THREE.NearestFilter or THREE.LinearFilter.

So, I tried to fix it. It works, when I put the filter:

```
var groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 5000, 5000, 96, 96 );
var grassTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/grass.jpg");
grassTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;//here is the filter
var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: grassTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var groundPlane = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
scene.add( groundPlane );
```

However, I tried another way, but at the end I got just the black plane:

```
var groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 5000, 5000, 96, 96 );
var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture({image: "images/grass.jpg", minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter}), side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var groundPlane = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
scene.add( groundPlane );
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the title and the question itself, since I got that my mistake was due to a small type error "grassTexture.minFilter = THREE.linearFilter;" instead of "grassTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;". But the second case is still not clear, so, I modified the question to make sense for the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a black plane in the second case because you are not passing the proper arguments to `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()`. You are passing an object `{}`. You would have to do something like this:

```
var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/grass.jpg" ),
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
} );
groundMaterial.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```

It is true that the texture loading is asynchronous, but without knowing the rest of your code, it cannot be determined if that is an issue here.

BTW, you likely do not need 18,000 faces in your `PlaneBufferGeometry`. Try

```
groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 5000, 5000, 1, 1 );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: The key here for me was adding the `minFilter` to the map of the `MeshBasicMaterial`. It wasn't working if I tried to just add it to the texture before.

Answer (score 1):

The texture is not downloaded and ready for use when you think it is.

In the first case the second statement requests an asynchronous loading of the texture. Two statements later the texture is assigned to a variable. It works just by luck.

In the second case you download and assign a texture all in one statement. Hardly enough time for the texture to be downloaded.

The proper way: (taken from http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/ImageLoader)

```
var groundMaterial;
...
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

// load a image resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'images/grass.jpg',

    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( image ) {
        // here you are guaranteed that the texture has downloaded so you can do something with it.
        groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: image, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
} );
```